# CodeIgniter iterate the outputted row over each instance of the Html

Tags: php, mysql, html, codeigniter

I can't get `<?php $row->entryData; ?></td>` to output. If I have two rows in the database I need it to iterate over each instance of the Html. It's not doing that though. It is outputting all the rows in one box. How can I get it to output in the correct box?

```
<?php   $userid = $this->session->userdata('userid');
        $query  = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM churchMembers WHERE cMuserId = '{$userid}'");
        $row = $query->row();
        $membersChurchId = $row->cMchurchId;
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT wp.entryData, wp.entryCreationDateTime, u.firstname, u.lastname, u.userid, u.defaultImgURI FROM users u
                                   INNER JOIN wallPosts wp ON wp.postingUserid = u.userid
                                   WHERE wp.wpChurchId = '{$membersChurchId}'");

        foreach ($query->result() as $row) { ?>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 500px; height: 107px" align="left">
                <td valign="top" style="padding: 3px; width: 101px;" rowspan="2">
                    <img id="defaultImg a0" src="<?php echo base_url().$row->defaultImgURI; ?>" width="95" height="96" /></td>
                    <td valign="top" class="style1" style="width: 124px">
                        <a class="font1"><?php echo $row->firstname . " " . $row->lastname; ?></a>
                    </td>

                    <td valign="top" class="right-align-button1" style="height: 35px; width: 269px;">
                        <a class="link-font1" id="like" href="#" style="width: 138px">Like</a> </span>
                        <span class="font2"> | </span>
                        <a id="comment" href="#" style="width: 138px" class="link-font1">Comment</a><br />
                        <span class="font2"><?php echo $row->entryCreationDateTime; ?></span>
                    </td>

                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" colspan="2" style="height: 72px">
                    <?php $row->entryData; ?></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Take another look at your HTML. You're making a new `<table>` for every `$row`, and you don't have a `<tr>` wrapping the first three `<td>`s. You've also got a random `</span>` in each iteration, it's quite a mess. Also, `id`s cannot have spaces or duplicate values. The inline styles and embedded SQL are not helping either.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/qS40Q3YY - so like this? I'm still not getting the value of `$row->entryData` to appear.

Comment: aren't you just missing the echo statement anyway? `<?php echo $row->entryData; ?>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have to change:

```
<?php $row->entryData; ?>
```

To

```
<?php echo $row->entryData; ?>  //you missed echo i guess
```

If everything else if fine in your code.